# Samba with multiple shares from the same server

Tags: raspberry-pi, samba

**Windows 10:**

I can't open more than one share of a server. Windows returns an error that the resource is not accessible.

Example: I open up `\\raspberrypi\one`. Now I try to open `\\raspberrypi\two` and Windows returns an error.

It is possible to access a second share by calling the IP instead of the name. `\\raspberrypi\one` & `\\192.168.0.5\two` are possible! A third share, either of the name or the IP, returns the same error.

**smb.conf:**

```
# Global parameters
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   netbios name = raspberrypi
   server string = Samba Server %v
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = yes
   vfs object = recycle
   recycle:maxsize = 0
[one]
   path = /mnt/library/one
   available = yes
   guest ok = no
   browsable = yes
   writeable = yes
   valid users = alice
   create mask = 0640
   directory mask = 0750
   force user = alice
[two]
   path = /mnt/library/two
   available = yes
   guest ok = no
   browsable = yes
   writeable = yes
   valid users = bob
   create mask = 0640
   directory mask = 0750
   force user = bob
[three]
   path = /mnt/library/three
   available = yes
   guest ok = no
   browsable = yes
   writeable = yes
   valid users = eve
   create mask = 0640
   directory mask = 0750
   force user = eve
```

All three shares are accessed with different Users & passwords.
Server is a RaspberryPi with a vfat HDD.

Comment: You can't do that - as has already been pointed out, authentication is done on a per-host basis rather than a per-user basis. It might be [worth updating your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/354921/edit) to explain what you're trying to achieve, because your configuration looks rather like it's half of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is likely due to the different users and passwords.  Windows associated the user with the host, not with the resource.  So your trick of using the IP address directly made windows think it was a different host and allowed different credentials.

One work around could be to have your pi use an IP address per resource.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Seems like [an authentication issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/de-DE/f3ee2c61-a5c7-48b3-a3bf-23ea323da699/connecting-to-multiple-shares-on-a-single-server-with-multiple-credentials-system-error-1219-?forum=itprovistanetworking):

> Please understand that this behavior is by design for security purpose, Windows only allow per user per SMB connect at a machine.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simple, fully controlled setup you can "trick" Windows by never using the IP of your pi as its share adress, but use hostnames instead.

For this edit the hosts file (please edit and include the path) and give it a separate name per share, e.g.

```
192.168.0.5 share1 share1
192.168.0.5 share2 share2
192.168.0.5 share3 share3
```

Then add shared drives in your win10 setup: `\\share1\one`, `\\share2\two` etc. Windows will identify these as different services (with one 'resource' each, called 'one', 'two' etc) and allow you to specify separate different credentials. PITA.