# Can't mount multiple shares from a Windows 10 machine on Linux

Tags: windows, samba, cifs, smb

I have a machine (winten) running Windows 10 Pro that exports two shares (X and Y).  I can mount either of those shares on my Arch Linux machine, but not both at the same time.  The configuration in /etc/fstab is exactly the same for both shares except for the name of the share:

```
//winten/x /mnt/winten/x cifs nofail,noserverino,vers=3.11,credentials=/etc/samba/private/winten-Net,uid=65534,gid=65534,file_mode=0444,iocharset=utf8,ro 0 0
//winten/y /mnt/winten/y cifs nofail,noserverino,vers=3.11,credentials=/etc/samba/private/winten-Net,uid=65534,gid=65534,file_mode=0444,iocharset=utf8,ro 0 0
```

The credentials file contains the name and password of a local user on the Windows machine.

Here's an example of trying to mount the shares:

```
# mount /mnt/winten/x
# mount /mnt/winten/y
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
# umount /mnt/winten/x
# mount /mnt/winten/y
# mount /mnt/winten/x
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

As you can see, whichever one I mount first works, and the second fails.

Here's the related output from dmesg:

```
[597888.074965] CIFS: Attempting to mount //winten/x
[597890.126132] CIFS: Attempting to mount //winten/y
[597890.129018] CIFS VFS: cifs_read_super: get root inode failed
[597899.512091] CIFS: Attempting to mount //winten/y
[597902.941119] CIFS: Attempting to mount //winten/x
[597902.942777] CIFS VFS: cifs_read_super: get root inode failed
```

**What do I need to do to get both shares mounted simultaneously?**

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354921/samba-with-multiple-shares-from-the-same-server), but it's going the other direction (mounting Samba shares on a Windows machine), and the problem turned out to be using different credentials for each share (but I'm using the same credentials).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have a solution unfortunately, but I do have a workaround that might suit your purposes:

This only seems to happen with SMB versions 3.0 and greater, so if you use `vers=2.1` instead of `vers=3.11` that should allow mounting multiple shares simultaneously.